# MS Graph API: "Requests must contain extension changes exclusively." when trying to create calendar event

Tags: office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to create a calendar event in MS Graph API using by posting the payload below. I've tried both from Graph Explorer and my code with the same result.

> Requests must contain extension changes exclusively.

If I try to create the event with no extension it works, and if I misspell the extension it says there's no extension with that name.

If I look at example 3 in this link it seems I should be able to create an event with an extension using one POST.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-schema-groups

```js
{
    "organizer": {
        "emailaddress": {
            "name": "Mattias Johansson",
            "address": "my_email@mail.com"
        }
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2019-06-25T14:00:00Z",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2019-06-25T15:00:00Z",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "ext46y2yz8p_activity": {
        "activityguid": "0050569A092E1ED98CEEF8728417C0D9"
    },
    "body": {
        "contenttype": "text"
    }
}
```

Update: 
I tried to update an existing record with the new attribute, and that works just as expected

Answer (score 1):

Just found that it is a known issue with Events, and also unfortunatly it is not possible to filter och schema extensions.

> Creating a resource instance and adding schema extension data at the
>   same time You cannot specify a schema extension in the same operation
>   as creating an instance of contact, event, message, or post. You must
>   first create the resource instance and then do a PATCH to that
>   instance to add a schema extension and custom data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/graph/known-issues#extensions